# How do I start a Mono Program on OS boot in Raspbian?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian.  I am trying to start a Mono program called StartBrowser.exe automatically when the system boots.  I added the following line to the /etc/rc.local file:

```
sudo mono /home/pi/Desktop/StartBrowser.exe
```

I also tried adding:

```
 sudo /home/pi/Desktop/StartBrowser.exe
```

The program does not start on boot.  When I run the same commands in the terminal the expected program starts.  What do I need to do to start "StartBrowser.exe" on system boot ?

Comment: Did you read [Run script with rc.local: script works, but not at boot](//stackoverflow.com/questions/7783341) first?

Comment: And did you really write to `/etc/rc/local` instead of `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: I continue to struggle with this issue.  I tried adding the following line using sudo crontab -e:  @reboot /home/pi/Desktop/StartBrowser3.exe  Still does not start on boot.

Comment: And what output do you get from the command in rc.local?  Redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a suitable temporary log if necessary.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you're using `sudo` in your rc.local script - root runs that, so sudo is just wasting valuable boot-time nanoseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few steps to accomplish this:

1. Make sure your application can be run as Windows Service ([check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer))
2. On RPi install mono-service with `sudo apt-get install mono-4.0-service`
3. Now you can add, at the end of the `rc.local` file, just before `exit 0` line this call:

`/usr/bin/mono-service -p:/directory/of/mono/app /directory/of/mono/app/app.exe`

`-p` switch is mandatory, otherwise no additional DLLs will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "mono-service" to run programs in the background.

You can run your compiled code like so:

```
mono-service /home/pi/Desktop/StartBrowser.exe
```

By default, this creates a lockfile in /tmp. You can change this by using the -l: option. 
In this way your service is running in the background